# Find by filename rather than ID in data mapper class

Tags: php, datamapper

I have an abstract data mapper class:

```
<?php
abstract class ADataMapper
{
    abstract public function addNew($dataObj);
    abstract public function update($dataObj);
    abstract public function find($primaryKey);
    abstract public function delete($dataObj);
}
?>
```

In a sub-class of `ADataMapper`, I need to find a row by a column that is not the primary key, specifically: 'filename'.

Would it be best to implement a method like `findByFilename($filename)` or is there another, simpler alternative? I feel like I am just adding more complexity than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I go for `getBySpecificKeyX` methods (so `getById()`/`getByParentId()` kind of family), and a general `search()` method which takes a construct/array of multiple searchterms and queries dynamically. That is a personal choice though.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a check within `find()`. If the argument is a string then call a private `findByFileName()` otherwise, `findById()`

Comment: Combine this with Wrikken so that you can pass in an `array('fieldName'=>'searchTerm')` etc. Then you can check if it's an `int` -> `findById()`, otherwise do a search.